# How to Parse a floating number in Haskell (Parsec.Combinator)

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I'm trying to parse a string in haskell using Parsec.Combinator library. But I can't find how to parse a floating value. My function only reads integer (with digit, but digit only parses a integer value).

```
parsePoint :: Parser Point
parsePoint = do
              string "Point"
              x <- many1 digit
              char ','
              y <- many1 digit
              return $ (Point (read x) (read y))
```

I searched for Text.Parsec.Number library but didn't find examples to how to use.

thanks for reading

Comment: There are several parsers for floating points: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec3-numbers-0.1.0/docs/Text-Parsec-Number.html#g:1 depending on the format(s) you want to allow.

Comment: Yes, I saw that library, but I didnt find any examples to how to use it

Comment: it is of type `Parsec s u m f`, so it can be used for any `Parsec` type with `Floating f` and `Stream s m Char`. Depending on the exact `Parser` you use (depending on which module of `Parsec` you work with), it will be specialised to parse `Text`, `ByteString`s, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several `Parser`s that can parse floats, for example [**`floating :: (Floating f, Stream s m Char) => ParsecT s u m f`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec3-numbers-0.1.0/docs/Text-Parsec-Number.html#v:floating). The `Parser` is just an alias for a special case of `Parsec`, depending on which module you use. For example [**`type Parser = Parsec Text ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.14.0/docs/Text-Parsec-Text.html#t:Parser).

If your `Point` thus accepts for example two `Float`s, you can use the [**`parsec3-numbers`** package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec3-numbers-0.1.0) and work with:

```
import Text.Parsec.Char(char, string)
import Text.Parsec.Number(floating)
import Text.Parsec.Text(Parser)

data Point = Point Float Float

parsePoint :: Parser Point
parsePoint = do
              string "Point "
              x <- floating
              char ','
              y <- floating
              return (Point x y)
```

This then can parse, in this case a string `"Point 3.14,2.718"`